# Excel does not display currency symbol(for example ¥) generated in my tcl code

Tags: html, excel, unicode, format, tcl

I actually am generating an MS Excel file with the currencies and if you see the file I generated (tinyurl.com/currencytestxls), opening it in the text editor shows the correct symbol but somehow, MS Excel does not display the symbol. I am guessing there is some issue with the encoding. Any thoughts?

Here is my tcl code to generate the symbol:

```
        set yen_val [format %c 165]
```

Comment: How does this relate to HTML (specified as the first tag)?

Comment: The URL http://tinyurl.com/currencytestxls does not work.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, the document is shared on google docs, if you click on the download link (the down arrow icon), you can download it and open it with a text editor..

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this does produce a Yen symbol (I put format string in double quotes here just for clarity with the formatting):

```
format "%c" 165
```

You can then pass it around just fine. The problem is likely to come when you try to output it; when Tcl writes a string to the outside world (with the *possible* exception of the terminal on Windows, as that's tricky) it *encodes* that string into a definite byte sequence. The default encoding is the one reported by:

```
encoding system
```

But you can see what it is and change it for any channel (if you pass in the new name):

```
fconfigure $theChannel -encoding $theEncoding
```

For example, on my system (which uses UTF-8, which can handle any character):

```
% fconfigure stdout -encoding
utf-8
% puts [format %c 165]
¥
```

If you use an encoding that cannot represent a particular character, the *replacement* character for that encoding is used instead. For many encodings, that's a “`?`”. When you are sending data to another program (including to a web server or to a browser over the internet) it is *vital* that both sides agree on what the encoding of the data is. Sometimes this agreement is by convention (e.g., the system encoding), sometimes it is defined by the protocol (HTTP headers have this clearly defined), and sometimes this is done by explicitly transferred metadata (HTTP content).

---

If you're writing a CSV file to be ingested by Excel, use either the “`unicode`” or the “`utf-8`” encoding and *make sure you put the byte-order mark in correctly*. Tcl doesn't write BOMs automatically (because it's the wrong thing to do in some cases). To write a BOM, do this as the *first* thing when you start writing the file:

```
puts -nonewline $channel "\ufeff"
```

Comment: If you're doing a real XLS or XLSX, I can't help; those are much more complex formats…